# How to join column names in one table to another tables rows?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in an MS Access database.  The first table decodes the column names for the second table.  I've provided a sample below.  I would like my output to replace the column codes used as column names in the second table with their proper names from table 1.  Is there an MS Access query that will do this table 2 column name to table 1 corresponding row join?  Thanks!

Table 1:

| Column Code | Column Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apples |
| B | Bananas |

Table 2:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 30 |
| 2 | 20 | 40 |

Desired Output:

| ID | Apples | Bananas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 30 |
| 2 | 20 | 40 |

Comment: Are your tables seriously laid out that way?

Comment: Yes.  Not my database.  Hate the layout but its what I have to work with.

Comment: @Eric: Such terrible schemas can origin from converting Json data where field names are named by attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In case of large number of ColumnNames, you can create the query by code:

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT ID"
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    SQL = SQL & " , " & rs("ColumnCode") & " AS " & rs("ColumnName")
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

SQL = SQL & " FROM Table2"

Dim qd As New QueryDef
qd.SQL = SQL
qd.Name = "QryColumnNames"
On Error Resume Next
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qd.Name
On Error GoTo 0
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Append qd
Set qd = Nothing
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but I will try:

```
SELECT
    t2.ID,
    (SELECT t1.[Column Name] FROM Table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.[Column Code] = 'A') AS Apples,
    (SELECT t1.[Column Name] FROM Table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.[Column Code] = 'B') AS Bananas
FROM
    Table2 AS t2;
```

this should give your expectation.

By the way, the way you wrote the sample tables is confusing.

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure why my tables showed that way in the question - they looked correct in the preview.  Is there no way to join on column name?  My data above was only a sample so I'd have to write out the solution for 100's of columns to do it that way.  Thanks again

Comment: What exactly are you looking to Join and where?

Comment: Table 2 Columns with Table1.[Column Codes] so I can pull back Table1.[Column Names] in place of Table2's actual column names (which are the codes).

Comment: Unnessecary complexity for a simple query: SELECT ID , A AS Apples , B AS Bananas FROM Table2